# Puppet: declare resource without containment

Tags: puppet

Puppet will contain all defined types declared inside another defined type (or class). As far as I understand, this implies that any declared source will depend on the container. This will result in a dependency loop:

```
define user {
}
define bar {
  user { $name: }
  ->
  Bar[$name]
}

bar { 'foo': }
```

```
Error: Could not apply complete catalog: Found 1 dependency cycle:
(User[foo] => Bar[foo] => User[foo])
```

Is there any way to avoid this? I ahve one specific instance where I would prefer that when `Bar[$name]` is declared, `User[$name]` be declared as well, but have `Bar[$name]` depend on `User[$name]`, not the other way around. Basically the same behavior as `require`, but for a defined type dependency.

Is there any way to accomplish this or is the only solution to have the manifest declaring `Bar[$name]` declare `User[$name]` as well (and then add the dependency on either the body of `bar` or in the declaring manifest?

---

A more realistic example:

```
define servize {}
define appserver {
  user { $name: }
  ->
  servize { $name: }
}

appserver { 'app': }

# the deploy application needs a directory owned by itself on startup
file { '/tmp/foobar':
  ensure => directory,
  owner  => 'app', # auto-require
}
->
Appserver['app']
```

Comment: Does not quite compute. `User[$name]` is declared by `Bar[$name]`, so what you really need is to have *all resources declared by* `Bar[$name]` *that are not* `User[$name]` to depend on `User[$name]`, correct? Would it not be straight forward to express just that?

Comment: @FelixFrank I already do that. But the dependency of `user` on `appserver` is still a problem. My example is a bit simplistic. Check my edit. In this case, you could break the loop by adding the dependency on `Servize` instead (and further break the abstraction...) but in more complex scenarios I sometimes still get loops from the service dependencies. It's simply unnecessary and undesirable to have `user` depend `appserver`. I wish that was a variant of `create/ensure_resources` that would create the resources and have them float in the graph (like classes).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, please do not redefine built-in types. List of all built-in types: https://docs.puppetlabs.com/references/latest/type.html.

If you have only one specific instance where $`Bar[$name]` depends on `User[$name]`
you can remove user from bar definition and create ordered_bar

```
  define ordered_bar {
    user { $name: }
    ->
    bar {$name : }
  }
```

That you only need to  create an instance of ordered_bar.
Please also read document about resource ordering in puppet: https://docs.puppetlabs.com/learning/ordering.html

Comment: This reinforces the adage that all problems can indeed be resolved with an extra layer of indirection. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can create the problematic resource as virtual. The feasability of this depends on the structure of your data layer.

```
define servize {}

user { 'app': }

define appserver {
  User<| title == $name |>
  ->
  servize { $name: }
}

appserver { 'app': }

# the deploy application needs a directory owned by itself on startup
file { '/tmp/foobar':
  ensure => directory,
  owner  => 'app', # still auto-require, but no ill effect
}
->
Appserver['app']
```